# Pass parameters to a function

Tags: c++

So, I have this:

```
struct Entry {
   int Key;
   char * Info;    
};

const int SIZE=100;
typedef Entry T;
typedef T MyList[SIZE];

void read_MyList(MyList & L, int & n)
```

mylist should be a pointer to a vector of struct, right? so I should pass just the name of the pointer, right? but what does that '&' mean? Am I passing a reference of the variable ? am I passing a reference of the pointer?

Comment: Perhaps a good idea here is to read a book, Bits about references and pointers read twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Entry {
   int Key;
   char * Info;    
};
```

means you have struct called entry

```
const int SIZE=100;
```

means you declare a constant

```
typedef Entry T;
```

means you give another name to entry, from now on `T` is another name to `struct Entry`

```
typedef T MyList[SIZE];
```

Means you give another name to Array of 100 `T`s, and call it: `MyList`

```
void read_MyList(MyList & L, int & n)
```

means you declare a function and give it one reference to `MyList` and one reference to `int`. reference means there is no copy, you work on the same original object or variable you sent to the function.

therefore:
to call it you must supply one `MyList` (not a pointer, a real object) and one `int`. the parameters are in/out parameters.

like:

```
int main(){
  MyList l1;
  int n=0;
  read_MyList(l1,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The best! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Must be

```
struct Entry {
   int Key;
   char * Info;    
};

const int SIZE=100;
typedef Entry T;
T MyList[SIZE];

void read_MyList(T* L, int & n)
```

and function call

```
int iEntries;
read_MyList(MyList, iEntries);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That makes sense.